# Javascript searcing and replacing?

Tags: javascript, search, replace

I want to change a string which start 'a' and end 'n'.

For example: "action" I want to replace 'ctio' and all starting 'a' and finishing 'n' with ''.

How can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return theString.replace(/\ba[a-z]*n\b/ig, '')
```

Comment: This would replace the entire word, he only needs to replace the letters between `a` and `n`.

Comment: thanks I want to use '<' and ' ' instead of 'a' and 'n' I can't do it

Comment: @sun: You want to strip HTML tags?

Answer (score 2):

in Javascript:

```
var substitute = "\"";
var text = "action";
var text = text.replace(/\b(a)([a-z]+?)(n)\b/gim,"$1" + substitute + "$3");
// result = a"n ... if what  you really want is a double quote here
```

Comment: and how can I replace with 'asdasd' instead of ''

Comment: @sundowatch: Just change the string assigned to `substitute`.

Comment: @Robusto: because of the non-greedy quantifier and the lack of a word boundary, this solution would have a problem with a word beginning with `a`, ending in `n` and having another `n` or `a` anywhere in the middle of the word.

Comment: @sundowatch: T.J. Crowder gave you the answer. I only want to add that a " is what your question looked like it wanted as the replacement string. The replacement can, of course, be any string.

Comment: thanks I want to use '<' and ' ' instead of 'a' and 'n' I can't do it

Comment: @sundowatch: Sure you can. '<' is a valid string for regexp searching. So is '>'. For example, /<\/*[a-z]+[^>]+>/gim will find any tag in a string of HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but I'm guessing going from "action" to "ctio"?

```
var foo = 'action';
if (foo.substr(0,1)=='a' && foo.substr(-1,1)=='n') {
  var bar = foo.substr(1,foo.length-2);
  alert(bar); // ctio
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this following

```
str.replace(/\ba(\w+)n\b/igm,'');
```

to the question in the comment use th following comment

```
var sub = "hello";
str.replace(/(<)(\w+)(")/igm,"$1" + sub + "$3");
```

Comment: your code is right. But I want to use '<' and ' ' instead of 'a' and 'n'. What must I do?